# mdf file is not appearing in App_data folder

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, connection-string, sql-server-2012-localdb

According to the e-book that I'm following, after debug and click on Log-in link, `.mdf` file should be created in `App_data` folder. Actually it is created, but does not show up in `App_data` folder in Visual Studio. Please help me to solve this!!

Connection string

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" 
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-HaveYouSeenMe-20150129221555;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-HaveYouSeenMe-20150129221555.mdf" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Did you try the "Show all files" button? Should be on your solutions explorer toolbar...